# constant parameters in a function

Tags: c++

```
class foo  
{  
    public:  
        void set(const int a)  
        {b=a;}  
    private:  
        int b;  
    };
```

Here `a` is a constant parameter which is assigned to a non const

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Whats the question? Are you asking if this is legal c++?

Comment: Maybe [Yoda](http://linguisticsmassey.files.wordpress.com/2009/11/yoda1.jpg?w=300&h=314) can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying the const modifier to a parameter indicates that the parameter may not be changed by the function. It does not mean, though, that if the parameter's value is assigned to another variable then that variable can't be changed.

The purpose is to assure callers that data they pass to the method will not be changed.

Comment: And in the example it doesn't matter that the argument is made `const`, because it's passed by value, so there's no way that modifying `a` inside the function would cause some outside variable to be changed.

Comment: Yep, in this case it just prevents a from being used as local storage or something along those lines. Very useful!